# Heroku Node.js server errors out upon running npm start script

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, server

I've been running a server for a year with no problems on heroku, but as of the last deployment it errors out with very little information upon running `npm start`, other than module updates very little has changed between the rollback build and this new deployment and yet one works and the other doesn't.

I've updated my packages, expressly stated my version of NPM and Node (as shown below with my package.json file), and tested multiple rollbacks to see what is different about them (which seems to be nothing). Since the error happens prior to my server code (shown below) I don't even know where to begin with diagnosis.

The console offers me very little explanation other than running `node server.js` isn't working:

```
2020-10-26T07:42:03.627918+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-10-26T07:42:07.108788+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-10-26T07:42:07.108829+00:00 app[web.1]: > wts-server@0.1.3 start /app
2020-10-26T07:42:07.108830+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2020-10-26T07:42:07.108830+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-10-26T07:42:08.624074+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-10-26T07:42:08.624385+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-10-26T07:42:08.628135+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! wts-server@0.1.3 start: `node server.js`
2020-10-26T07:42:08.628296+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-10-26T07:42:08.628470+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2020-10-26T07:42:08.628623+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the wts-server@0.1.3 start script.
2020-10-26T07:42:08.628776+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-10-26T07:42:08.639120+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-10-26T07:42:08.639338+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-10-26T07:42:08.639462+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-10-26T07_42_08_630Z-debug.log
2020-10-26T07:42:08.690140+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

This is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "wts-server",
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "verbose": true
  },
  "version": "0.1.3",
  "description": "Server for West Coast Megagames Watch the Skies Prototype.",
  "main": "server.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix ../reactapp",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "test": "jest --detectOpenHandles --coverage"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.18.3",
    "npm": "6.14.6"
  },
  "author": "John T. Cleveland",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "config": "^3.3.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "^4.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-async-errors": "^3.1.1",
    "helmet": "^3.23.3",
    "joi": "^17.3.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.10",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
    "supports-color": "^7.2.0",
    "winston": "^3.3.3",
    "winston-mongodb": "^5.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^26.6.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2"
  }
}
```

The server itself doesn't seem to be activating at all, as normally I'd be getting info messages. The error seems to be happening prior to code and I'm wondering if I've just missed something small.

`server.js` even though it's not being hit at all:

```
const express = require('express'); // Import of EXPRESS to create routing app
const http = require('http'); // Import of the NODE HTTP module to create the http server
const { logger } = require('./middleware/log/winston'); // Import of winston for error logging

logger.info('Starting boot-up for WTS Game server...');

require('supports-color'); // Allows colors for debug panel

// Start up proceesses
logger.info('Loading Start-up proceesses...');
const app = express(); // Init for express
logger.info('Express app started...');
const server = http.createServer(app); // Creation of an HTTP server
logger.info('HTTP server created...');
require('./middleware/log/logging')(); // Bootup for error handling
require('./routes/sockets')(server); // Starts websocket
require('./routes/routes')(app); // Bootup for Express routes
require('./middleware/mongoDB/db')(); // Bootup of MongoDB through Mongoose
require('./config/config')(); // Bootup for special configurations
require('./middleware/production/prod')(app); // Production compression and middleware

app.use(express.static('public'));

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000; // Server entry point - Node Server
server.listen(port, () => logger.info(`WTS Server started on port ${port}...`));
```

The code all runs fine in the development environment, and until this merge ran fine on heroku, without an actual error to diagnose I'm at a loss as to why it won't boot now. Any assistance would be fantastic.

Comment: What was the change that you made in the latest deployment?

Comment: Unfortunately, this was a large update to the server-side code (hundreds of changes), basically a complete overhaul of routes, models, and some of the server logic, all of which don't occur as it doesn't make it to `line 5` in server.

In `package.json` all dependencies were updated and explicit `engine` for node and npm was also added.